# Is a service needed to trigger an alarm in an alarm app?

Tags: android, android-service

I'm making an alarm app and wondering if it is needed to implement a service to maintain an alarm to ring in the future. Can't 'PendingIntent' do the job? We can assign every alarm time a unique ID and it should ring.

The only case where I see a service is needed is when the phone reboots and we need a service to respond to the reboot broadcast by setting the alarms again as I assume rebooting will destroy the 'PendingIntent'.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're referring to using `AlarmManager`.

Yes, you can supply a `PendingIntent` created from an `Activity`, and it should work. This is not recommended mainly for UX (and not technical) reasons -- unless your app is a timer, abruptly interrupting what the user is doing can be very annoying. Hence, a service is usually tasked with showing a notification when the alarm "sounds", and tapping on this alarm opens the activity.

As you indicated, you need to listen for `BOOT_COMPLETED` because alarms are wiped out when the device is restarted.

Comment: What if i want the user to be abruptly interrupted, as the stock Android alarm does? Then, only the part about reboot is valid, right?

Comment: You are correct. But even then, you would _probably_ want a service to display a notification indicating that will happen (as the stock Android alarm does) :) But it's not _technically_ required.